# Google Spreadsheet - disable editing

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to **disable EDIT in a few columns** of a google spreadsheet **for shared users** - so that only the owner has the edit permissions for all rows and columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this answer [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Docs/thread?tid=3e4e88285a1e1284&hl=en) maybe it will help

1. Create a spreadsheet.
2. On the first sheet, Sheet1, create the style of the form you want for people to enter information. Leave this sheet unprotected
3. When you've got the form looking good, duplicate Sheet1.
4. Rename the duplicated sheet 'Summary', or something appropriate. Protect this sheet.
5. On the sheet Summary, make links to the data on Sheet 1, so mirrors Sheet1. 
   for example, in cell A2 on the Summary sheet, type in    =Sheet1!A2
6. Have users enter data on Sheet1
7. Have users refer to the Summary sheet for the calculations or the summary of the information.

Comment: Can I disable some cells after a certain time like post midnight?

Answer (score 9):

You can protect subParts of a worksheet in google docs.  Select the cells you want to protect and then perform following clicks  --> "Data" --> "Name and Protected Ranges" --> Name your range and check the checkBox "protect"

Answer (score 3):

As I know, you can lock only single sheets, no custom columns. So maybe if you will use separate sheets for protected data, it is possible to solve it. For protecting sheets, you can try `Tools -> Protect sheet...`

Answer (score 0):

More complete answer here:
It's solvable

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/144687?hl=en

Comment: Could you please at least summarize the linked answer