# How to restrict users from editing their own input?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a google spreadsheet and plan to share it with my teammates, the first few rows are locked and it can be only edited by me. Everyone will be able to edit all the blank cells, however, I would like to restrict others from editing their own input - once a user write anything to a blank cell, that cell can be only edited by that user.

I tried to search online but what i found is to lock a cell from everybody once edited.

I think it could be done by using some Google App Script, but don’t know how.

Answer (score 0):

Tell the users that protect the cell that they edited or do that automatically by using Google Apps Script and an installable onEdit or onChange trigger.

Related

- [Google Spreadsheet - disable editing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7173755/1595451)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just found an other solution for this: by creating protected sheets for each user and use the query function to get the data from their sheets to a protected master sheet. It seems eaiser for me in this way.

Comment: @bluery Pleas post your soluction as an answer. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer